# How to align according to commas

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Could I get some help on how I should go about if I want to align the inputs of the table with respect to the commas?

Here is the code that I have for the table

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
                          &                        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Player 2}                  \\
                          &                        & B                     & N                     \\ \cline{3-4} 
\multirow{2}{*}{Player 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-c_{1}$ , $-c_{2}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\mu - c_{1}$ , $-d$} \\ \cline{3-4} 
                          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$-d$ , $\mu - c_{2}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$0$ , $0$} \\ \cline{3-4} 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! The `siunitx` package provides a special column type `S` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`eqparbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<id>][<align>]{<stuff>}` to set all `<stuff>` labelled with `<id>` in a box of the same width. By default it centres the content, but you can adjust the horizontal `<align>`ment to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
                            &                        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Player 2}                  \\
                            &                        & B                     & N                     \\ \cline{3-4} 
  \raisebox{-.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{Player 1} 
                            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{  \eqmakebox[c1]{$-c_1$} , \eqmakebox[c2][l]{$-c_2$}}   & 
                                                       \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\eqmakebox[c3]{$\mu - c_1$} , \eqmakebox[c4]{$-d$}} \\
  \cline{3-4} 
                            & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \eqmakebox[c1][r]{$-d$} , \eqmakebox[c2]{$\mu - c_2$}} & 
                                                       \multicolumn{1}{c|}{     \eqmakebox[c3][r]{$0$} , \eqmakebox[c4][l]{$0$}} \\
  \cline{3-4} 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by splitting the two right columns into two each:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ccr@{, }l|r@{, }l|}
    && \multicolumn{4}{c}{Player 2} \\
    && \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{N} \\
    \cline{3-6}
    \multirow{2}{*}{Player 1}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{B}
    & $-c_1$ & $-c_2$
    & $\mu - c_1$ & $-d$ \\
    \cline{3-6}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{N}
    & $-d$ & $\mu - c_2$
    & $0$ & $0$ \\
    \cline{3-6}
 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]